# How can i get the current node from context menu in a TreeView in Powershell?

Tags: winforms, powershell, treeview

I create a treeview in powershell and i added a context menu into every items.
I try to get now, when i click on an context menu item, the selected node.

```
$ctxCreateSiteMenuItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ctxCreateSiteMenuItem.Text = "Create a site"        
$ctxCreateSiteMenuItem.Add_Click({CreateSite $this.Parent.Node})
```

When i looked to $this, it is my current context menu item. $this.Parent this is my list of context menu items. $this.Parent.parent return empty value.
In c# ou VB the solution is really easy because you have access to the sender but here i can not find a way to do it.
For information, i right click to open the context menu. I already try to select a node and after open the context menu but it didn't work.

```
function CreateSite{
param ( 
            $selectedNode,
            $sender,
            $eargs          
        )

Write-host $sender
Write-host $eargs
```

Comment: `add_Click({param($sender,$eargs) <# use $sender in here #>})`

Comment: I add it as parameter but the value is empty. Maybe i am doing wrong .

Comment: Sender or $this is finally the same. I am at the same point @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the right-clicked (not necessarily the Selected) node in a global variable - it's not nice but it works:

```
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Form1"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600, 300)

$TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$TreeView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
$TreeView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500, 200)
$Form.Controls.Add($TreeView)

$rootNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
$rootNode.text = "Root"
$rootNode.name = "RootName"
[void]$TreeView.Nodes.Add($rootNode)

for ($i=0; $i -lt 6; $i++) {
    $subNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
    $subNode.text = "Node{0}" -f $i
    $subNode.name = "NodeName{0}" -f $i
    [void]$rootNode.Nodes.Add($subNode)
}

$ctxMenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
$ctxCreateSiteMenuItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$ctxCreateSiteMenuItem.Text = "Create a site"        
$ctxCreateSiteMenuItem.add_Click({ param($sender, $eargs)
    Write-Host "SelectedNode: $global:selectedNode"
})
$ctxMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(@($ctxCreateSiteMenuItem))

$TreeView.ContextMenu = $ctxMenu

$TreeView.add_NodeMouseClick({ param($sender, $eargs)
    $global:selectedNode = $eargs.Node
})

$rootNode.Expand()

# Show Form // this always needs to be at the bottom of the script!
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Yeah finally i did that, i put the treeview varable global and i get the selected node using Treeview.SelectedNode

Comment: The issue i have now is i need to left click before right click to set the selectedNode.

Comment: The add_NodeMouseClick is for both riht and left click?

Comment: Yes.  I wrote the above specifically NOT to require you to left-click the node first, because it sounded like you didn't want that.  The add_NodeMouseClick sets the global variable if you left-click OR right-click but if you put your code in the add_Click for the menu item, and use the global variable there, that will only work when the menu item itself is selected.

Comment: If you want the node to become the selected node, when someone right-clicks on it, you could set `$sender.SelectedNode = $eargs.Node` in the add_NodeMouseClick instead and then use SelectedNode in your `add_Click` handler.